# Проблемы с RegExp и replace()

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

Помогите разобраться. Проблема заключается в том, что функция replace с прямым указанием substr работает с "i" флагом как и положено

```
var patternSearch = new RegExp('радиусом шварцшильда', "igu");
console.log('радиусом Шварцшильда'.replace(patternSearch,'КЛЮЧ'));  //выдает КЛЮЧ
```

а вот полученный через форму `<input type="text" name="newkey[]" value="радиуcом шварцшильда" style="display: none;">` - не работает.

```
var this_key = $(this).find('input').val();
var patternSearch = new RegExp(this_key, "igu");
console.log('радиусом Шварцшильда'.replace(patternSearch,'КЛЮЧ'));  //выдает радиусом Шварцшильда
```

Comment: Если что-то идет не так - в первую очередь проверьте входные данные. `console.log(patternSearch)` - подозреваю, выведет undefined или пустую строку.

Answer (score 1):

```
var this_key = $('input').val();
var patternSearch = new RegExp(this_key, "igu");
let result = 'радиуcом шварцшильда'.replace(patternSearch,'КЛЮЧ');  

console.log(result)
```

Нахождение элемента input через $(this)(window) возвращало undefined.
Поменял на поиск через селектор